# Function within a Function Getting Not Defined Error

Tags: python-3.x, function

I'm a total beginner to Python. I have been learning for a little less than a month now and I'm trying to make a little code for fun. Rose is a naughty doggo and I wanted the code to print "No", and stop running the code if the user tries to enter her as a good dog.

We had a similar assignment in my programming class for graduate school and I'm still trying to wrap my brain around having a function within a function so I thought making a code about my dogs would be a funny/easier way to learn this.

```
def goodDogs(goodDogFormula):
    gooddog1 = input(str('Name your first good dog: '))
    gooddog2 = input(str('Name your second good dog: '))
    goodDog = gooddog1 and gooddog2
    return goodDog   

def goodDogFormula(gooddog1,gooddog2,goodDog):
    if gooddog1 or gooddog2 == 'Rose':
        print('That is not a good dog')
    else:
        print(goodDog)

goodDogs(goodDogFormula())
```

I keep getting this error:

```
NameError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-8c56e6ac1e71> in <module>
      8         else:
      9             print(goodDog)
---> 10 goodDogs(goodDogFormula())
     11 

NameError: name 'goodDogFormula' is not defined
```

Comment: `input(str('Name your first good dog: '))` I think you mean `str(input('Name your first good dog: '))` because anything in `''` is already a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic (if I'm understanding you correctly) is thus:

1. Get input from user on the dogs
2. Call goodDogFormula on the input
3. Print something based on the input.

So you really should do something different, such as:

```
def goodDogFormula(goodDog1, goodDog2):
    if goodDog1 == 'Rose' or goodDog2 == 'Rose':
        print('That is not a good dog')
    else:
        print(goodDog1)

def goodDogs():
    gooddog1 = str(input('Name your first good dog: '))
    gooddog2 = str(input('Name your second good dog: '))
    goodDogFormula(goodDog1, goodDog2)


goodDogs()
```

Note, you had several errors in syntax, which I fixed.

```
 if gooddog1 or gooddog2 == 'Rose':
```

That's invalid, the `or` operator doesn't work like that. You put `or` between two booleans and it will return true if at least one of the booleans are true. See my above code for how to do that properly.

Answer (score 0):

To be exact your code is a little too bad

```py
def goodDogs():
    gooddog1 = input(str('Name your first good dog: '))
    gooddog2 = input(str('Name your second good dog: '))
    goodDoggos = [gooddog1, gooddog2]
    def goodDogFormula(goodDogs):
        for dognum, dog in enumerate(goodDogs):
            if dog == "Rose":
                del goodDogs[dognum]
                print('Rose is not a good dog')
        print(*goodDogs)
        return goodDogs
    return goodDogFormula(goodDoggos)
```

I think this is the logic you wanted.
Test first and correct me if i am wrong